# Circle Icon not resize to fit in screen

Tags: java, android, android-studio, icons

I have in my application a circle icon:

[image]

When I run my application I see the icon looks like this:

[image]

Any idea of how I can remove the white background and make the icon bigger?

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use the middle of your circle only. This should enlarge the icon and remove alpha that is replaced by whiteness when android sizes the icon...

Answer (score 0):

create and set your icon from [AndroidAssetStudio](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher).